# ROS Publish Stereo Image From 2 USB Cameras

Tags: webcam, publish-subscribe, ros, stereoscopy

I have to monocular USB cameras and I want to use ROS to make it a stereo camera. I am having a hard time finding a ROS package that publishes there 2 images in this format:

```
/my_stereo/left/camera_info
/my_stereo/left/image_raw
/my_stereo/right/camera_info
/my_stereo/right/image_raw
/my_stereo_both/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_both/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_l/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_l/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_r/parameter_descriptions
```

How can I do this? Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc

You can change the publish topic name according to the documentation.

Comment: I already looked at that but it doesn't show me what I can use to publish the image.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://jeffzzq.medium.com/ros2-image-pipeline-tutorial-3b18903e7329) provides an example, how exactly to publish the images.

I'm struggling with the disparity topic and posted a question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/409680/ros2-image-pipeline-for-point-cloud-creation-using-stereo-camera-no-disparity/).

According to the already mentioned [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) from 2016, the stereo_image_proc node was supposed to do a lot of job, but it looks like that it doesn't exist in ROS2 version. There are two nodes: disparity_node and point_cloud_node.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33243460)